# Dockerfile ADD tar.gz does not extract on ubuntu VM with Docker

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, dockerfile, tar

I have a Docker Image which I want to build and when I run the build command on my Windows and Mac Docker it works fine and builds correctly, but if I run the same Dockerfile-Build on a Ubuntu-Server VM with docker I get an error.

The critical part of my Dockerfile is:

```
[...]
# Dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-utils curl git tar gzip
# Install Go
ENV GO_VERSION 1.8
WORKDIR /tmp
ADD https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go$GO_VERSION.linux-amd64.tar.gz ./
RUN mv go /usr/local/
[...]
```

But on the Ubuntu-server VM is fails at the `RUN mv go /usr/local/`-step

And producing the following error:

```
Step 10/24 : RUN mv go /usr/local/
 ---> Running in 6b79a20769eb
mv: cannot stat ‘go’: No such file or directory
```

And I suppose it does not extract the downloaded tar.gz correctly (but the download works)

Do you guys have any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a known issue with 17.06 and patched in 17.06.1. The documented behavior is to download the tgz but not unpack it when pulling from a remote URL. Automatically unpacking the tgz was an unexpected change in behavior in 17.06 that they reverted back to only downloading the tgz in 17.06.1.

Release notes for 17.06 (see the note at the top): https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/releases/tag/v17.06.0-ce

Release notes for 17.06.01: https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/releases/tag/v17.06.1-ce

Issue: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33849

PR of Fix: https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/pull/89

---

Edit, the minimize the number of layers in your image, I'd recommend doing the download, unpack, and cleanup as a single `RUN` command in your Dockerfile. E.g. here are two different Dockerfiles:

```
$ cat df.tgz-add
FROM busybox:latest
ENV GO_VERSION 1.8
WORKDIR /tmp

ADD https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go$GO_VERSION.linux-amd64.tar.gz ./
RUN tar -xzf go$GO_VERSION.linux-amd64.tar.gz \
 && rm go$GO_VERSION.linux-amd64.tar.gz

CMD ls -l .

$ cat df.tgz-curl
FROM busybox:latest
ENV GO_VERSION 1.8
WORKDIR /tmp

RUN wget -O go$GO_VERSION.linux-amd64.tar.gz https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go$GO_VERSION.linux-amd64.tar.gz \
 && tar -xzf go$GO_VERSION.linux-amd64.tar.gz \
 && rm go$GO_VERSION.linux-amd64.tar.gz

CMD ls -l .
```

The build output is truncated here...

```
$ docker build -t test-tgz-add -f df.tgz-add .
...

$ docker build -t test-tgz-curl -f df.tgz-curl .
...
```

They run identically:

```
$ docker run -it --rm test-tgz-add
total 4
drwxr-xr-x   11 root     root          4096 Aug 31 20:27 go

$ docker run -it --rm test-tgz-curl
total 4
drwxr-xr-x   11 root     root          4096 Aug 31 20:29 go
```

However, doing a single `RUN` to download, build, and cleanup saves you the 80MB of download from your layer history:

```
$ docker images | grep test-tgz
test-tgz-curl               latest                                     2776133659af        30 seconds ago      269MB
test-tgz-add                latest                                     d625455998ff        2 minutes ago       359MB
```

Comment: Ok, but I am using 17.06.1:
`$ docker --version` `Docker version 17.06.1-ce, build 874a737`

Comment: Or do you mean, that since version 17.06.1 ADD does not extract tarballs anymore automatically and I should do it manually?

Or what do you recommend?

Comment: Is that your client or server version? If it's still broken in current releases then I'd follow up on their issue.

Comment: @cobz And just to be clear, that should be the version on the server where you ran the build, not where you're trying to run the container, or client version.

Comment: Yes, it was the version where I tried to build. 
So indeed 17.06.1 on my ubuntu server does not unpack tar.gz with ADD automatically. 17.06.0 on Windows does.

I now implemented a conditional that manually untars it when it hasn't been done by ADD to be compatible.

I wasn't sure whether the ADD should unpack it automatically or not and what is the preferred behaviour

Comment: @cobz Mea culpa, I had it reversed like you, the documented behavior is to not unpack the tgz when pulling from a remote url. So the automatic unpacking behavior that got introduced in 17.06 was reverted back in 17.06.1.

Comment: You can also skip creating the downloaded file and use the unix pipes `RUN curl http://your.url.com/file.tar.gz | tar xzf - -C /your/docker/location`. You also get the download progress in `stderr`.
For wget i think it is `RUN wget -O - http://your.url.com/file.tar.gz | tar xzf - -C /your/docker/location`

Comment: Using `RUN` means that `wget` (or `curl`) and `tar` have to be in the image just to unpack the tarball, even if the content of the image itself never needs any of those commands

Comment: @kbolino you can use a multi-stage build if you need the final environment to not include the commands needed to build the image.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this ever worked, but now Docker doesn't untar remote URLs. Quite annoying.

> If  is a *local* tar archive in a recognized compression format (identity, gzip, bzip2 or xz) then it is unpacked as a directory. Resources from remote URLs are not decompressed.